# Why do we use $\psi$ instead of a straightforward probability?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, complex-numbers

What is the advantage/purpose of using $\psi$ for wavefunctions and getting the probability with $|\psi|^2$ as opposed to just defining and using the probability function?

Comment: We have got time-evolution equation [(Schrodinger equation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) for $\psi$ and not for $|\psi|^2$

Comment: One motivation is the double slit interference. It is (i) the superposition of wavefunction; (ii) $|\psi|^2$ to get the diffraction pattern. If we use $\rho:=|\psi|^2$ directly without superposition of wavefunction, superposition of probability is incorrect, and it will be awkward to think about square root of $\rho$ and possibly with phase factor..

Comment: [This thread](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57595/probability-amplitude-in-laymans-terms) should answer the question.

Comment: See @NikolajK's thread, which is indeed wonderful. But in my experience this question is often asked with the mistaken belief that quantum mechanics and complex $\psi$ are "harder" to understand than probability. IMO this is absolutely the wrong way around, [see here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/90819/26076)!

Answer (score 4):

One purpose of using $\Psi$ rather than just the probability density is to match observation. Dealing only with probability density isn't sufficient.

Imagine you can send particles through two adjacent slits toward a detector screen. You'll find an interesting pattern that looks like an interference phenomenon is happening. This is called the *double slit experiment* if you want to take a look. There's no way to explain the pattern that appears based only on the probability densities corresponding to each slit alone. In other words, if slit #1 alone produces a density $\rho_1(x)$ on the screen, and slit #2 alone produces a density $\rho_2(x)$ on the screen, there is no way to combine $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ to get the actual density $\rho$ that's observed.

Using the probability amplitude $\Psi$ allows us to predict the actual pattern.

I should mention that, historically, this was not the motivation for introducing $\Psi$, but it's a convenient way to view the need after-the-fact. I believe $\Psi$ first appeared in Schrodinger's equation as a way to get the allowed energies of a bound system. This is an equation in $\Psi$, not $\rho$. It wasn't until after the concept of $\Psi$ that the connection $\rho=|\Psi|^2$ was made. Nonetheless, as user36952 pointed out, we have an equation describing how $\Psi$ develops in time, not how $\rho$ develops.